# SQL Locking not implemented correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have implemented a SQL tablockx locking in a Procedure.It is working fine when this is running on one server.But duplicate policyNumber occurs when request comes from two different servers.

```
declare @plantype varchar(max),
@transid varchar(max),
@IsStorySolution varchar(10),
@outPolicyNumber varchar(max) output,
@status int output  -- 0 mean error and 1 means success
)
as
begin

BEGIN TRANSACTION

Declare @policyNumber varchar(100);
Declare @polseqid int;

-- GET POLICY NUMBER ON THE BASIS OF STORY SOLUTION..
IF (UPPER(@IsStorySolution)='Y')
BEGIN
select top 1 @policyNumber=Policy_no  from PLAN_POL_NO with (tablockx, holdlock) where policy_no like '9%' 
and pol_id_seq is null and status='Y';
END


ELSE
BEGIN
select top 1 @policyNumber=pp.Policy_no  from PLAN_POL_NO pp with (tablockx, holdlock) ,PLAN_TYP_MST pt where pp.policy_no  like PT.SERIES+'%'
and pt.PLAN_TYPE in (''+ISNULL(@plantype,'')+'') and pol_id_seq is null and pp.status='Y' 
END

-- GET POL_SEQ_ID NUMBER



select @polseqid=dbo.Sequence();



--WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03';


set @policyNumber= ISNULL(@policyNumber,'');

-- UPDATE POLICY ID INFORMATION...

Update PLAN_POL_NO  set status='N',TRANSID =@transid , POL_ID_SEQ=ISNULL(@polseqid,0) where Policy_no =@policyNumber 

set @outPolicyNumber=@policyNumber;

if(@@ERROR<>0) begin GOTO Fail end

COMMIT Transaction
set @status=1;
return;
Fail:
If @@TRANCOUNT>0
begin
Rollback transaction
set @status=0;
return;
```

This is function which i have called::

```
CREATE function [dbo].[Sequence]()      
returns int  
 as    
begin    
declare @POL_ID int

/***************************************
-- Schema name is added with table name in below query 
-- as there are two table with same name (PLAN_POL_NO)
-- on different schema (dbo & eapp).
*****************************************/

select @POL_ID=isnull(MAX(POL_ID_SEQ),2354) from  dbo.PLAN_POL_NO 

return @POL_ID+1

end
```

Comment: You should format your function as code (like you did with your stored procedure Ctrl+K).  I tried to edit your post but the site doesn't recognize the changes.

Comment: ok i will do that...please provide the resolution of the problem.

Comment: I'll need more information in order to help you.  How can a stored procedure call come from two separate servers?  Are you erroneously sending the same request twice?  Or do you mean that the conflict is caused by two separate requests that are originating from two separate servers?

Comment: actually i have sql environment on which i have written a proc.So while doin UAT when a request come from only single server this handles perfectly. But when concurrent request comes from 2 different server at same time.this problem occurs.

Comment: First thing I notice is that you're missing an "END" inside your "Fail:" block.  Second thing I notice is that you don't need a separate "SET" command to take care of the ISNULL - you can do that in the select statement, itself.  Other than that, your code appears that it should be working?

Comment: I think your table lock is only holding for the select statement, itself.  Once the select statement is finished, the lock is released and the queued query (from your second server) runs and has the same policy number - because it's completing BEFORE the first SP's "UPDATE" command?  I think I could fix it, but I'm not certain enough to post an answer, so I'll hold off for now.

Comment: 1) End keyword missing:: I have missed while writing this post.In original it is written correctly.                                                                                            2)Set statement::  Ignore this i will manage this in original code.

Comment: Nevermind - I see you have an exclusive lock and are using holdlock, so the lock should be held until the transaction commits or rolls back, which would mean that either the problems you're describing are impossible - or that Microsoft's documentation is incorrect?

Comment: @stan shaw- ok...please help.We are planning to move to production on 31 dec.

Comment: @StanShaw - my friend recommends a solution is this right:               select top 1 @policyNumber=ISNULL(Policy_no,'')  from PLAN_POL_NO with (Rowlock)  where policy_no like '9%' and pol_id_seq is null and status='Y' order by Newid();                                                                               please suggest

Comment: it is under UAT....seems to going well...:)...planning to Productionize soon...unexpected scenario occurs there...finger cross

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because concurrent requests are both getting the same POL_ID_SEQ from your table dbo.PLAN_POL_NO.

There are multiple solutions to your problem, but I can think of two that might help you and require none/small code changes:

1. Using a higher transaction isolation level instead of table hints.

In your stored procedure you can use the following:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

This will make sure that any data read/modified during the SP block is transactionally consistent and avoids phantom reads, duplicate records etc.  It will potentially create higher deadlocks and if these tables are heavily queried/updated throughout your application you might have a whole new set of issues.

2. Make sure your update to the dbo.PLAN_POL_NO only succeeds if the sequence has not changed. If it has changed, error out (if it changed it means a concurrent transaction obtained the ID and completed first)

Something like this:

```
Update dbo.PLAN_POL_NO 
SET    status      ='N',
       TRANSID     = @transid,
       POL_ID_SEQ  = ISNULL(@polseqid,0)
WHERE Policy_no = @policyNumber
      AND POL_ID_SEW = @polseqid - 1

IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1
BEGIN
   -- Update failed, error out and let the SP rollback the transaction
END
```

Comment: my friend recommends a solution is this right: select top 1 @policyNumber=ISNULL(Policy_no,'') from PLAN_POL_NO with (Rowlock) where policy_no like '9%' and pol_id_seq is null and status='Y' order by Newid(); please suggest

Answer (score 0):

A `WITH (HOLDLOCK)` option in the function might suffice.

The HOLDLOCK from the first queries may be being applied at a row or page level that then DOESN'T include the row of interest that is queried in the function.

However, the function is not reliable since it is not self-contained.  I'd be looking to redesign this such that the Sequence can generate AND "take" the sequence number before returning it.  The current design is fragile at best.